# Restoring Purchases on Multiple Devices

Tags: ios5, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have an App which has `inApp Purchases Client - Sever Model` integrated.

I'm having difficulty in tracking the `Restoration and Delivery of the Products`.

I'm tracking the `UDID` of the user that purchases the product and Server delivers the product to that particular `UDID`.

```
  Now if i want to restore the previous purchases on a different device, 
  how will i deliver the content? As my database has a different UDID?
```

On what basis we must track the purchases so that we can deliver it on all the devices???

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the UDID, Apple may reject your app (privacy problems, you can see it [here](http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/24/apple-udids/)).

Related to the problem:

Why do you need the UDID? In the restore process you will receive the receipt of each transaction. You can send this data to your server, and there, you can check it against the Apple service. If it's correct the server deliver the content to the devive. There is no need for the UDID.

Comment: I'm aware of the UDID deprecation by Apple,but how will i able to deliver the purchase on user's device without UDID??

Comment: And how will i manage the purchases on different devices with same Apple id?

Comment: When you check the receipt against your server, this one, returns the content directly as the response. Maybe a plist or JSON with data to download. So you do not need the UDID.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this could be as follows:

Generate a unique identifier (for example with CFCreateUUID) for the user when they purchase something. Send this ID to the server along with the receipt. Store a record on the server. When the user wants to share this product on another device they have to click a "Share to other device" button. When they do, an email is sent to an email address specified by them. This email contains a link yourapp://id=. When a user opens this on another device, a "Restore" action is sent to your server. Check the record for the given ID and keep track of a "restore" counter so that the user can only restore on a maximum of say 5 devices.

I know... this is ridiculous, but I haven't found a better way to deal with it. 
Hope this helps.